# Is there a way to get the readability stats for a Word document without going through grammar & spelling check (on a Mac)?

Tags: macos, microsoft-word

As far as I can see, the only way to get the readability statistics for a document (or a selection in a document) is to start the "Spelling & Grammar" tool, go through all the spelling and grammar issues, and then finally landing on the Readability Statistics page. Is there any way to just jump right to Readability Statistics?  For a huge doc with lots of unrecognized words (in this case, lots of code and java class names) it is so tedious to get through the entire spelling and grammar process.

Note: I am using Microsoft Word for Mac 16.16.20 (200307).

[image]

Comment: Does it not allow unchecking spelling and grammar, while leaving readability statistics checked on the Mac edition?

Answer (score 1):

You need a VBA macro to display these values without completing the spell check.
VBA seems to be [supported on MacOS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/office-mac).

The document should be first saved as `.docm` to allow macros, then use
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to enter the VBA editor, use menu *Insert > Module*
and set the contents to the following:

```
Sub Readability()
    Dim DocStats As String
    DocStats = ""
    For Each stat In ActiveDocument.Content.ReadabilityStatistics
        DocStats = DocStats & stat.Name & " : " & stat.Value & vbCrLf
    Next stat
    MsgBox DocStats, vbOKOnly, "Readability Statistics"
End Sub
```

You may use <kbd>F5</kbd> in the editor to run/test the macro.
In everyday use you may run the macro from the
[Developer tab](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-show-the-developer-tab-on-the-ribbon?view=vs-2017)
or
[Assign a macro to a ribbon button](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/assign-a-macro-to-a-button-728c83ec-61d0-40bd-b6ba-927f84eb5d2c)
or do
[Adding a Macro to the Quick Access Toolbar](https://wordribbon.tips.net/T006011_Adding_a_Macro_to_the_Quick_Access_Toolbar.html).
Remember to run the spell-check first, before testing the macro.

Reference: [Only Showing Readability Statistics](https://word.tips.net/T001784_Only_Showing_Readability_Statistics.html).

Comment: I can't find any way to get VBA working on my version of Word : ( .. Insert > Module is not there.

Comment: I'm not on the Mac, so let's go slow. Did Alt+F11 get you into the VBA editor, or alternatively did you get the Developer tab?

Comment: Nope. Nor any other modifier key + F11

Comment: Did you get to show the Developer tab on the ribbon? If yes, do you see a "Macros" item on the left?

Comment: No Developer tab. If I go into preferences, it seems turning this on may be limited to those with an "Office 365 Subscription."

Comment: I don't have an Office 365 Subscription and I enabled it successfully, but on Windows. Instructions for Mac are [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/show-the-developer-tab-in-word-e356706f-1891-4bb8-8d72-f57a51146792#OpenDevTab=m).